# Angular list all or according to the category

Tags: angular, list, angular-ng-if

```
books=[{
    title:"Life is good",
    author:"benny",
    category:"life"
    },{
    title:'Canned in',
    author:"francis",
    category:"style"
  }];

<ng-container *ngFor="let book of books">
 <div *ngIf="book.category == cat">
  <h3>{{book.title}}</h3>
  <h4>{{book.author}}</h4>
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

I have a working code...
     it displays the item with the category,
     but I want to display all the item not checking the category, when `cat==all`
     I do not want to duplicate this code

```
<div *ngIf="book.category == cat">
 <h3>{{book.title}}</h3>
 <h4>{{book.author}}</h4>
</div>
```

to get all items, but rather implement some logic in the same div to have 
all the options in it.

Like: all, category name, category name...

Comment: what is cat? It is impossible to understand. your question is like puzzle

Comment: I have a select tag having (all,life,style) cat will have any one these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an OR condition,

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let book of books">
        <div *ngIf="cat=='all' || book.category==cat">
            <h3>{{book.title}}</h3>
            <h4>{{book.author}}</h4>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a filter [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) instead. Then your filtering logic is abstracted from the template and you could extend it as you see fit in future revisions. Don't forget to include it in your `declarations` in the `@NgModule`.

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcbfjq)

**categoryFilterPipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'categoryFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class CategoryFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(books: {category:string}[], category:string): any {

        return (category && category !== 'all')
            ? books.filter(_ => _.category === category)
            : books;
    }
}
```

**html template**

```
<div *ngFor="let book of books | categoryFilter : cat">
  <h3>{{book.title}}</h3>
  <h4>{{book.author}}</h4>
</div>
```